# How to change color of all shapes in window with C# and XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

### Brief

I am trying to programmatically change the colour of specific elements at runtime. The project currently uses Telerik and I am able to change the theme at runtime: This works as expected with no issues. I can't, however, figure out how to change the fill or stroke colour at runtime of custom shape elements in XAML.

Within my project I have a `ResourceDictionary` file named **_Icons.xaml** that contains vector shapes to use as the content for other controls (such as buttons).

---

### Code

#### App.xaml.cs

I am using the following code to change the theme's marker colours at runtime.

```
GreenPalette.Palette.MarkerColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF000000");
```

#### _Icons.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyNamespace">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Box">
        <Viewbox>
            <Rectangle Width="357" Height="357" Fill="#000000"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="BoxOutline">
        <Viewbox>
            <Rectangle Width="357" Height="357" StrokeThickness="45" Stroke="#000000"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </ControlTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```
<telerik:RadButton>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Box}" Height="58"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0">Box</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</telerik:RadButton>

<telerik:RadButton>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource BoxOutline}" Height="58"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0">BoxOutline</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</telerik:RadButton>
```

---

### Question

In **_Icons.xaml** I have the following lines:

- `<Rectangle Width="357" Height="357" Fill="#000000"/>`
- `<Rectangle Width="357" Height="357" StrokeThickness="45" Stroke="#000000"/>`

Given the following line in **App.xaml.cs**:

```
GreenPalette.Palette.MarkerColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF000000");
```

How can I either...

1. Programmatically change the values of `Fill` **and/or** `Stroke` (an element that only has `Fill` set should only change the `Fill` value and not add a `Stroke` attribute) from the **App.xaml.cs** file? *Or ...*
2. Bind the values in XAML for `Fill` or `Stroke` to receive the value given by my **App.xaml.cs** file?

Thank you for taking the time to read my question. Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make a brush resource. Use it via DynamicResource. Update the resource.

Comment: Thanks @EdPlunkett I’ll give that a try the next time I have a chance

Answer (score 0):

First i advise you to eject that controls off your resource sheet so you can actually control them properly.

When you do that, go the code behind your control  and just use dependency property of type 'Color' of the 'SolidColorBrush' that is used by the background and then bind it by element name, you gotta build the project at least once before attempting to bind.

Here is how you write a dependency property

hint: in VS write 'propdp' and hit tab twice to bring up a template, but you can use mine for now.

```
   public Color _color
            {
                get { return (Color)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
                set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
            }

            public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = 
   DependencyProperty.Register("_color", typeof(Color), typeof(Fileentity), null);
```

after you build once go to the xalm and put this inside your rectangle:

```
        <Grid.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding 
         _color,ElementName=YourControlName" />
        </Grid.Background>
```

if you do it right you will be able to access this property when inserting the control on you Page like

```
<local:YourcontrolName _color="{x:Bind MyColorProperty }"/>
```

where 'MyColorProperty' is a property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

An alternative way is to use a datacontext directly on the usercontrol and just bind your color to one of its properties like:

```
    public YourControl(){

        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MyClassDataContext();

   var myContext= (MyClassDataContext)this.DataContext;
      _color=MyContext.MyColorProperty;}
```

Where MyClassDataContext is any given class that contains a Color property(MyColorProperty) of your choosing.

You need a Dependency  property here as well that binds to your Controls xalm like i showed before.

I know all this is might too hard to grasp at once, thats cause it requires basic knowledge of MvvM.